# How do I stop windows messenger changing my status from "available" to "away"?

Tags: windows-live-messenger

How do I stop windows messenger changing my status from "available" to "away" when my computer is idle?

Comment: What do you mean, if you leave your computer or if you lock your computer? locking your computer generates another proces and will mark you as away immediatly. If you mean when you're simply leaving your computer for a while, then genesis' answer will do.

Answer (score 1):

Click on your profile name -> Advanced options -> Personal -> Appear as "away" if I'm inactive for <kbd>5</kbd> minutes.

change <kbd>5</kbd> to <kbd>0</kbd>